# should spilled records always be equal to mapinput records or mapoutput records in mapreduce using hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on the matrix multiplication example using mapreduce in hadoop. I want to ask that should spilled records always be equal to mapinput and mapoutput records. 
I am having spilled records different from mapinput and mapoutput records

here is the output of one of the tests that i am getting:

```
Three by three test
   IB = 1
   KB = 2
   JB = 1
11/12/14 13:16:22 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
11/12/14 13:16:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201112141153_0003
11/12/14 13:16:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/12/14 13:16:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/12/14 13:16:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201112141153_0003
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 17
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=2
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=1464
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=528
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=2998
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=384
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=36
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=18
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=735
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=15
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=108
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=1350
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=54
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=54
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 128 bytes
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/MatrixMultiply/out
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
11/12/14 13:16:46 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 14
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=89412
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=37206
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=37390
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=164756
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=9
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=9
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=15
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=9
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=18
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=180
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=15
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=15
11/12/14 13:16:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=9
...........X[0][0]=30, Y[0][0]=9
Bad Answer
...........X[0][1]=36, Y[0][1]=36
...........X[0][2]=42, Y[0][2]=42
...........X[1][0]=66, Y[1][0]=24
Bad Answer
...........X[1][1]=81, Y[1][1]=81
...........X[1][2]=96, Y[1][2]=96
...........X[2][0]=102, Y[2][0]=39
Bad Answer
...........X[2][1]=126, Y[2][1]=126
...........X[2][2]=150, Y[2][2]=150
```

This example is described here along with code:

http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html

Can you please suggest me that where is the problem and how can I get it right? Thanks

WL

Comment: I also want to mention that while running on the standalone mode then it works fine where spilled records are equal to the mapinput and output records (which are 18)but in pseudodistributed mode it does not work and spilled records are not equal to the mapinput and mapoutput records.

Comment: Spilled means, that they have to be spilled to disk because the RAM wasn't enough in sort/shuffle phase. So this should be zero at the best or very low.

Comment: ahhh ok. infact I am new to this so after looking at the output in standalone mode which is equal number of spilled records and having the correct answer, I thought that it must have been same...can you please suggest me after looking at the output that what might be the problem and how to solve it. thanks

Comment: Without seeing the implementation, this is hard to say.

Comment: implementation code is in the link I mentioned in question. so if you have interest and time then please have a look on the code. thanks

Comment: Well, I'm not going to debug this. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

According to *Hadoop: The Definitive Guide*, "Spilled Records" counts the total number of records that were spilled to disk over the course of a job and includes both map and reduce side spills. It is possible for the "Spilled Records" count to be zero, and that is perfectly fine. In general, spilled records means you have exceeded the amount of memory available in the map output buffer. Having a small number of "Spilled Records" is generally not an issue. The settings for the available RAM are `io.sort.mb` and `io.sort.spill.percent` in your `mapred-site.xml`. If performance were an issue, you would want to tune these to minimize the spilled records. The presentation [Optimizing MapReduce Job Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf) has more details, specifically slides #12 and #13. If you spill more than once, then you pay a 3x penalty in IO due to needing to merge the spills. If "Spilled Records" is more than "Map Output Records" + "Reduce Output Records" then you are doing more than one spill. Note that ultimately, the amount of RAM is limited by the heap size of your Java VM, so you may need to either increase your cluster size or increase the number of map tasks by increasing the input splits for a given job in order to reduce the number of spills.

In your specific example, "Spilled Records" is larger, so you are spilling more than once.